# Redux – Reducer depending on other state

Tags: redux

I have a Redux app that is displaying a list of Properties based on a set of Filters (user input).

Quick description of my state:

1. `filters` – Filters values object...
2. `properties` – Repo of all properties available on page
3. `visibleProperties` – List of properties with current filters applied

The problem is when I dispatch & set a new filter value, I need to filter `properties` based on `filters` *new state* and to store the result in `visibleProperties`.

So I came up with this solution:

```
export function setBedroomFilter (value) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    // 'SET_FILTER' action
    dispatch(setFilter('bedroom', parseInt(value)))

    // New state
    const { filters, properties } = getState()

    // 'FILTER_PROPERTIES' action (Depending on new state)
    dispatch(filterProperties(properties, filters))
  }
}
```

And `visibleProperties` reducer can do its work:

```
// case 'FILTER_PROPERTIES'...
visibleProperties = action.properties.filter(item => item.bedroom >= action.filters.bedroom)
```

Is this approach totally fine?

Comment: Suggestion: It sounds like you are duplicating your properties in the redux store. You should probably store the only _filter state_ in redux, and do the _actual_ filtering at the container level. You wouldn't have to dispatch another action to filter, because the container will automatically filter out the properties passed in based on props (filter and properties).

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. However I simplified my example for the purpose of the question. The reason I have "duplicated" `properties` state, is because one of them _keeps_ a cached version of the filtered list based on current filters serialisation. So (I think) I cannot do what you've suggested (filtering in container), cause I would lost that particular filtered list and would have to filter again if same filters are applied later on. Hence I call one (more) action to filter `properties` and cache the result in so called duplicated `properties` state. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `dispatch`:

> Dispatches an action. This is the only way to trigger a state change.
>
> The store's reducing function will be called with the current
>   getState() result and the given action synchronously. Its return value
>   will be considered the next state. It will be returned from getState()
>   from now on, and the change listeners will immediately be notified.

It's a synchronous function and it's totally fine to use in the way you've described(as long as `setFilter` is synchronous). However, if you're doing asynchronous operation in `setFilter`,(assuming that Promise returned from setFilter) you should chain your dispatch calls like this:

```
dispatch(setFilter('bedroom', parseInt(value))).then(() => {
   // New state
   const { filters, properties } = getState()

   // 'FILTER_PROPERTIES' action (Depending on new state)
   dispatch(filterProperties(properties, filters))
}
```

Another option might be using selectors. Please check it out:
https://github.com/reactjs/reselect